# This is the process of writing an array pointer

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

This is the process of writing an array pointer. `int *pj = *pi;`, `*pi` is the value of the array, so why is there no error? (Assuming that `pi` contains the address value of the second row, I think `*pi` is 5. If 5 is the address value?)

I don't understand.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[3][4]={{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}};

    for(int (*pi)[4]=arr; pi<arr+3; pi++){
        for(int *pj = *pi; pj<*pi+4;pj++){
            printf("%4d",*pj);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what this question is asking. `pi` is a variable of type "pointer to `int[4]`". `*pi` is therefore an `int[4]`. `*pi` can therefore also experience array-to-pointer decay and be used to initialize an `int*`.

Comment: *so why is there no error?* -- Don't fall into the trap of trying potentially bad code, and expecting "bad results" like crash or seg fault.  C++ does not work this way.  You know bad code by visual inspection of the code.  In your case, the code seems perfectly fine -- but again, do *not* attempt to write "proof-of-concept" code in C++ in the hopes of always getting "an error".

Comment: Is this C or C++? If it's C++ you *really* should be using `auto` instead of clunky expressions like `int (*pi)[4] = ...` In C you can just ignore the size part, it's a pointer, and if you safely traverse it you'll be fine. Note here, *safely*. Your `pj < *pi + 4` is probably going to work, but it'd be way better to set an end pointer in advance that's `&pi[4]` to make it clear what's going on.

Comment: If `pi` contains the address of the second row `&arr[1]`, `*pi` will be the second row `arr[1]` which will decay to a pointer (of type `int*`) to the first element of the second row `&arr[1][0]`, and `**pi` will be the first element of the second row `arr[1][0]` which contains the value `5`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you refer to a fixed array itself, it can *decay* into a pointer to its 1st element.

`arr` is an `int[3][4]` array, ie an array of 3 elements, where each element is an `int[4]` array.

`pi` is a pointer to an `int[4]` array.

Thus:

`pi = arr`
is the same as:
`pi = &arr[0]`
ie the address of the 1st element in the outer array.

`arr + 3`
is the same as:
`&arr[0] + 3` aka `&arr[3]`
ie the address after the 3rd element of the outer array.

So, the outer loop iterates through elements `arr[0]`..`arr[2]`, where `pi` points at the current element on each iteration.

`pj` is a pointer to an `int`.  `*pi` yields a reference to the current `int[4]` array, which then *decays* into an `int*` pointer to its 1st `int`.

Thus:

`pj = *pi`
is the same as:
`pj = &(*pi)[0]`
ie the address of the 1st `int` in the current `int[4]` array.

`*pi + 4`
is the same as:
`&(*pi)[0] + 4` aka `&(*pi)[4]`
ie the address after the 4th `int` in the current `int[4]` array.

So, the inner loop iterates through elements `(*pi)[0]`..`(*pi)[3]`, where `pj` points at the current element on each iteration.

---

Maybe the following diagrams will help you.

Think of `arr` being laid out in memory like this (it is not really, but it can be *treated* as if it were):

```
+----+----+-----+---+
| 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  |
+----+----+----+----+
| 5  | 6  | 7  | 8  |
+----+----+----+----+
| 9  | 10 | 11 | 12 |
+----+----+----+----+
```

On the 1st iteration of the outer loop, `pi` points here:

```
   +----+----+-----+---+
-> | 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  |
   +----+----+----+----+
   | 5  | 6  | 7  | 8  |
   +----+----+----+----+
   | 9  | 10 | 11 | 12 |
   +----+----+----+----+
```

And on each iteration of the inner loop, `pj` iterates through the inner array:

```
   +----+----+-----+---+
   | 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  |
   +----+----+----+----+
     ^
```

```
   +----+----+-----+---+
   | 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  |
   +----+----+----+----+
          ^
```

```
   +----+----+-----+---+
   | 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  |
   +----+----+----+----+
               ^
```

```
   +----+----+-----+---+
   | 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  |
   +----+----+----+----+
                    ^
```

When the inner loop finishes, the 2nd iteration of the outer loop runs, where `pi` now points here:

```
   +----+----+-----+---+
   | 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  |
   +----+----+----+----+
-> | 5  | 6  | 7  | 8  |
   +----+----+----+----+
   | 9  | 10 | 11 | 12 |
   +----+----+----+----+
```

And `pj` now iterates through that inner array:

```
   +----+----+----+----+
   | 5  | 6  | 7  | 8  |
   +----+----+----+----+
     ^
```

```
   +----+----+----+----+
   | 5  | 6  | 7  | 8  |
   +----+----+----+----+
          ^
```

```
   +----+----+----+----+
   | 5  | 6  | 7  | 8  |
   +----+----+----+----+
               ^
```

```
   +----+----+----+----+
   | 5  | 6  | 7  | 8  |
   +----+----+----+----+
                    ^
```

When the inner loop finishes, the 3rd and final iteration of the outer loop runs, where `pi` now points here:

```
   +----+----+-----+---+
   | 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  |
   +----+----+----+----+
   | 5  | 6  | 7  | 8  |
   +----+----+----+----+
-> | 9  | 10 | 11 | 12 |
   +----+----+----+----+
```

And `pj` now iterates through that inner array:

```
   +----+----+----+----+
   | 9  | 10 | 11 | 12 |
   +----+----+----+----+
     ^
```

```
   +----+----+----+----+
   | 9  | 10 | 11 | 12 |
   +----+----+----+----+
          ^
```

```
   +----+----+----+----+
   | 9  | 10 | 11 | 12 |
   +----+----+----+----+
               ^
```

```
   +----+----+----+----+
   | 9  | 10 | 11 | 12 |
   +----+----+----+----+
                    ^
```

By the time both loops are finished, the entire array has been iterated through, and every `int` has been printed.

Answer (score 1):

Given this definition of `arr` ...

> ```
>     int arr[3][4]={{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}};
> ```

... in this definition of `pi` ...

> ```
> int (*pi)[4]=arr;
> ```

, the sub-expression `arr`, which has array type `int[3][4]`, is automatically converted to a pointer to the first array element.  That element has array type `int[4]`, and a pointer to it has type `int(*)[4]`, which is exactly matched to the type declared for `pi`. So all is well.

In that context, then, consider this definition of `pj`:

> ```
> int *pj = *pi;
> ```

`pi` has type `int(*)[4]`, so `*pi` has type `int[4]`, an array type.  Because it has an array type, the value of this sub-expression is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, which in this case is an `int`.  A pointer to that has type `int *`, which is exactly matched to the type declared for `pj`, so again, all is well.

> Assuming that `pi` contains the address value of the second row, I think `*pi` is 5.

The last conclusion is mistaken.  `pi` does contain the address of a row, so `*pi` designates *the whole row*, not just one element of it.  The type of the pointer is important here.